# Okay so I'm coding a roll the dice game on java

Tags: java, if-statement

This is the code I have, but I want it to be able to roll the dice based on the number of trials the user inputs and then display the frequencies of each face.

This code isn't working as I would expect.

Also I would like to change the switch cases to `if` and `else if` statements, if anybody could help me out with that would be amazing, I've been working on this for a while now.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DieRoll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Random randomNumbers = new Random(); 
        int one=0;
        int two=0;
        int three=0;
        int four=0;
        int five=0;
        int six=0;
        int trials;
        int face;

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of trials");
        Scanner scan= new Scanner (System.in);
        trials= scan.nextInt();

        for(int rolls= 1; rolls==trials; rolls++);{

            face=  randomNumbers.nextInt(6) + 1;

             // determine roll value 1-6 and increment appropriate counter
             switch ( face ) 
             {   
                case 1:
                   ++one; // increment the 1s counter
                   break; 
                case 2:
                   ++two; // increment the 2s counter
                   break;
                case 3:
                   ++three; // increment the 3s counter
                   break;
                case 4:
                   ++four; // increment the 4s counter
                   break;
                case 5:
                   ++five; // increment the 5s counter
                   break;
                case 6:
                   ++six; // increment the 6s counter
                   break; // optional at end of switch
             }
          }

        System.out.println( "Face\tFrequency" ); // output headers
          System.out.printf( "1\t%d\n2\t%d\n3\t%d\n4\t%d\n5\t%d\n6\t%d\n",
             one, two, three, four,
             five, six );

            scan.close();



    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop:

1. Remove the semicolon (`;`) just after the `for(int rolls= 1; rolls==trials; rolls++)` line.
2. Change:

   ```
   for(int rolls= 1; rolls==trials; rolls++)
   ```

   to:

   ```
   for(int rolls= 1; rolls<=trials; rolls++)
   ```

As far as changing switch to `if`-`else`-`if`, not sure why you would want to do this, but simply write it as:

```
if(face == 1){

  one++;

}

else if(face ==2){

  two++;

}
```

and so on..

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I missed that ;

Comment: Glad I could help. Please go ahead and take it as the accepted answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this:

```
public class Main {

    private static final Random RANDOM_NUMBER_GENERATOR = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberOfTrials;
        int[] facesFrequencies = new int[6];

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of trials");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        numberOfTrials = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.close();

        for (int numberOfRolls = 1; numberOfRolls <= numberOfTrials; numberOfRolls++) {
            int face = rollDice();

            if (face == 1) {
                facesFrequencies[0] += 1;
            } else if (face == 2) {
                facesFrequencies[1] += 1;
            } else if (face == 3) {
                facesFrequencies[2] += 1;
            } else if (face == 4) {
                facesFrequencies[3] += 1;
            } else if (face == 5) {
                facesFrequencies[4] += 1;
            } else if (face == 6) {
                facesFrequencies[5] += 1;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Face\tFrequency");
        for (int i = 0; i < facesFrequencies.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d\t\t%d%n", i, facesFrequencies[i]);
        }
    }

    private static int rollDice() {
        return RANDOM_NUMBER_GENERATOR.nextInt(6) + 1;
    }
}
```

- I've put the results (`int one` to `int six`) into an array. `facesFrequencies[0]` will be the same as `int one`.
- The `;` after `for (...)` is syntactically incorrect.
- Switch statement is replaced with if statement.